# Defining module names with Typescript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, typescript

I'm trying to use TypeScript with RequireJS but I'm getting the following error:

> Mismatched anonymous define() module.

I understand this is because Typescript is not emitting a module name and I'm loading the scripts into the page myself (I'm doing this as they are defined as a pre-defined bundle in the MVC project).

Currently the outputted .js looks like this:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery"], function(require, exports, $) {...
```

When I need it to emit:

```
define("MODULE_NAME" ["require", "exports", "jquery"], function(require, exports, $) {...
```

Is this possible with Typescript or should I look at replacing the bundle for minimization with Require.js's own optimization?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ASP.NET and the integrated [script bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), you are correct: The problem is that the bundle contains multiple anonymous modules. While it is good, common practice to work with anonymous modules (and let some compressor/optimizer do the naming later), this won't work for ASP.NET bundling because it only concatenates the input JS files. The solution is to make TypeScript create named modules. And this is possible with TS, so the answer to your question

> Is this possible with Typescript

is definitely: Yes!

TypeScript 1.4 added the ability to emit [AMD named modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-amd-module-) to the compiler, like this:

```
///<amd-module name='NamedModule'/>
export class C {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the code generation (which is correct). The issue is that you probably have a script tag loading this JavaScript file. It should only be loaded by RequireJS, using data-main or as a dependency of another module.

See : http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

Remove the script tag